# How to change base url for S3 bucket in angular

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular9

I am unable to change the base url for aws bucket while accessing data from bucket in angular. Any idea??

Comment: can you please describe a little more?

Comment: Actually I have to access some data from s3 bucket. For that I need to change the base url.

Comment: Why do you need to change project's baseUrl to access amazon s3 bucket's data??
You should be able to access data to the project if bucket's permission is right.

Comment: my domain url is different from aws base url

Comment: does it matter? you can put the entire url to src tag.